# Replicate .each() and $(this).find() with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, find, each

I want to basically do the exact next logic but with vanilla javascript

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if (
        $(this).find("> .someClassName:nth-child(2)").length &&
        $(this).find("> .someClassName:last-child").length
    ) {
        $(this).addClass("className");
    }
});
```

I tried the next logic but it didn't work ..

```
const selectedLIs = document.querySelectorAll("li");
selectedLIs.forEach(element => {
    if (
        element.querySelector("> .someClassName:nth-child(2)") && element.querySelector("> .someClassName:last-child")
    ) {
        element.classList.add("className");
    }
});
```

It gives me this error ...

> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '>
>   .someClassName:nth-child(2)' is not a valid selector.

So how can I achieve the same thing with just Javascript?

Comment: I think that's because of `>`. Try to remove it.

Comment: Can you include the HTML at the question?

Comment: @guest271314 The HTML is dynamic, and I basically want to select the direct child of the <li>.

Comment: @Ruby What is the HTML after the dynamic content has been appended to the `document`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `>` from the selector

```
element.querySelector(".someClassName:nth-child(2)") && element.querySelector(".someClassName:last-child")
```

Comment: But how can I target the target child of the <li> and check it exist or not?

Comment: @Ruby, if `element` is the `li` then it should return the first matched element in the selector....